# Synchronizing Dygraphs using Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, dygraphs

I am trying to synchronize two dygraphs using 'extras/synchronizer.js', as it is done here http://dygraphs.com/tests/synchronize.html .I an importing both plugin and dygraph library itself, but get the module error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iULmd.png)

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?  Facing the same issue over here.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, but not particularly pretty.  In the .vue file you want to construct a graph in:

```
// imports main dygraph class from /node_modules and adds it to window scope
import _DygraphRoot from 'dygraphs'
window.Dygraph = _DygraphRoot

// tacks on .synchronizer to the window scoped Dygraph
require('dygraphs/src/extras/synchronizer')
```

You then access Dygraphs in your .vue file from the window like so:

```
let graph = new window.Dygraph(...)
```

Comment: Is there a better solution than this?